# Progressive Disclosure in C++ API

Tags: c++, api, design-patterns

Following my reading of the article [*Programmers Are People Too*](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1071731) by Ken Arnold, I have been trying to implement the idea of progressive disclosure in a minimal C++ API, to understand how it could be done at a larger scale.

Progressive disclosure refers to the idea of "splitting" an API into categories that will be disclosed to the user of an API only upon request. For example, an API can be split into two categories: a base category what is (accessible to the user by default) for methods which are often needed and easy to use and a extended category for expert level services.

I have found only one example on the web of such an implementation: the [db4o](https://github.com/lytico/db4ohttp://) library (in Java), but I do not really understand their strategy. For example, if we take a look at [**ObjectServer**](https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/master/db4oj/core/src/com/db4o/ObjectServer.java), it is declared as an interface, just like its extended class [**ExtObjectServer**](https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/master/db4oj/core/src/com/db4o/ext/ExtObjectServer.java). Then an implementing [**ObjectServerImpl**](https://github.com/lytico/db4o/blob/11fa71fc00feff0ef3a4fd1e39ed01e00c9311bc/db4o.cs/src/com/db4o/cs/internal/ObjectServerImpl.java) class, inheriting from both these interfaces is defined and all methods from both interfaces are implemented there.

This supposedly allows code such as:

```
public void test() throws IOException {
    final String user = "hohohi";
    final String password = "hohoho";
    ObjectServer server = clientServerFixture().server();
    server.grantAccess(user, password);

    ObjectContainer con = openClient(user, password);
    Assert.isNotNull(con);
    con.close();

    server.ext().revokeAccess(user); // How does this limit the scope to 
                                     // expert level methods only since it
                                     // inherits from ObjectServer?

    // ...
});
```

My knowledge of Java is not that good, but it seems my misunderstanding of how this work is at an higher level.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand the article correctly, Progressive Disclosure is a documentation technique, not a programming methodology. You organize the documentation into separate sections for the common stuff and the advanced stuff.

Comment: This probably makes the question more appropriate for programmers.SE or softwareengineering.SE.

Comment: @Barmar The way I read it, it's more than just documentation: you actually delegate the "advanced" functions into a separate interface.

Comment: A followup of this can be found [here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/336840/how-to-implement-progressive-disclosure-in-c-api/336843#336843)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java and C++ are both statically typed, so what you can do with an object depends not so much on its actual dynamic type, but on the type through which you're accessing it.

In the example you've shown, you'll notice that the variable `server` is of type `ObjectServer`. This means that when going through `server`, you can only access `ObjectServer` methods. Even if the object happens to be of a type which has other methods (which is the case in your case and its `ObjectServerImpl` type), you have no way of directly accessing methods other than `ObjectServer` ones.

To access other methods, you need to get hold of the object through different type. This could be done with a cast, or with an explicit accessor such as your `ext()`. `a.ext()` returns `a`, but as a different type (`ExtObjectServer`), giving you access to different methods of `a`.

Your question also asks how is `server.ext()` limited to expert methods when `ExtObjectServer` extends `ObjectServer`. The answer is: it is not, but that is correct. It should not be limited like this. The goal is not to provide *only* the expert functions. If that was the case, then client code which needs to use both normal and expert functions would need to take two references to the object, just differently typed. There's no advantage to be gained from this.

The goal of progressive disclosure is to hide the expert stuff until it's explicitly requested. Once you ask for it, you've already seen the basic stuff, so why hide it from you?